# Surface area of ellipsoid by using a diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis

Given the ellipsoid $E = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}\leq 1, a,b,c > 0 \}, $ I need to find a diffeomorphism $\phi: U\rightarrow V$ and use it to find the area of the ellipsoid by using the result that for each Borel set $B\in U, \lambda (\phi(A))=\int_A |\text{det} D\phi(x)| d\lambda^2(x).$

If we do the substitution $x'=x/a, y'=y/b, z' = z/c$ one gets the equation of a sphere. Using spherical coordinates, $x'=r\cos(\psi)\sin(\theta), y'=r\sin(\psi)\sin(\theta), z'=r\cos(\theta)$ one gets a relationship between the initial coordinaes and the spherical ones $x=ar\cos(\psi)\sin(\theta), y= br\sin(\psi)\sin(\theta), z=cr\cos(\theta).$ Is this correct ? I have here some doubt.
We can define the map: $$ U:=]0,2\pi[\times]0,\pi[, \,\,\,\,\Phi:U \rightarrow \Phi(U), \,\,\Phi(\psi, \theta)=\begin{pmatrix} 
ar\cos(\psi)\sin(\theta) \\ 
br\sin(\psi)\sin(\theta) \\ 
cr\cos(\theta) 
\end{pmatrix}. $$

I am not sure if this is what I have to do. Can somebody provide some suggestion or comment ? Thanks.

Comment: Your function $\Phi$ is a good one to use, but notice the technicality that $\Phi(U)$ is not the entire ellipsoid $E$, so you'll still need to argue that $E\setminus\Phi(U)$ has measure zero and so $E$ and $\Phi(U)$ have the same area.  An alternative method is to use two different versions of $\Phi$, which together cover $E$, and then take $\lambda(E) = \lambda(\Phi_1(U)) + \lambda(\Phi_2(U)) - \lambda(\Phi_1(U)\cap\Phi_2(U))$.

Comment: It also occurs to me that if your assignment is to use a diffeomorphism involving $E$, then they may intend for you just to transform to the primed variables and then use the known fact (if you do know it) that the volume of the unit ball is $\frac43\pi$.  Then you have no technicalities about missing pieces or overlaps to deal with.

Comment: Actually, there is one issue with $\Phi$. Are you trying to get the surface area of the ellipsoid, or the volume of the ellipsoidal ball that you called $E$? If it's the surface area that you want, then you don't have $r$, since $r=1$ on the surface. But if it's the volume, then $U$ needs another dimension to for $r$, and you have $U = \mathopen]0,1\mathclose[\times\mathopen]0,2\pi\mathclose[\times\mathopen]0,\pi\mathclose[$ with $\Phi(r,\psi,\theta)=\cdots$ (what you wrote at the end).

Comment: Thanks. It is about the surface and not the volume. The problem is that with the given $\Phi$, we have a map between a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3.$ SO I have a problem in setting the determinant appropriately, since there is no r argument. Can you provide a suggestion ?